# ForEach Loop, Execute Command for Each Randomly Named Image

Tags: c#

I'm using Movie Maker Timeline Control in C# to try and randomize the order of pictures in Windows Movie Maker. I have the form set up, but I seem to encounter a problem with the importing of photos. My code needs to be able to import multiple randomly named images (ex: IMG_xxxx.JPG). I'm able to individually import a specifically named image, but when I try to use a foreach loop, it fails.

My code:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            openFolder.Description = "Open a folder containing pictures for the slideshow!";

            if (openFolder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // this code right here
                string folderPath = openFolder.SelectedPath;

                string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.JPG");
                foreach (string file in fileArray)
                {
                    folderPath = folderPath + "\\" + file;
                    float duration = 4;
                    float startpos = 0;
                    timelineControl.AddImageClip(timelineControl.GetImageTrackIndex(), folderPath, startpos, (startpos + duration));
                    startpos = startpos + 4;
                }

                /* string image = "C:\\Users\\OSR\\Desktop\\jpgs\\img.JPG";
                float duration = 4;
                timelineControl.AddImageClip(timelineControl.GetImageTrackIndex(), image, 0, duration); 
                */
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Next time, select a folder and click open!", "Selection Cancelled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/MrB928Ri

Program: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaVsV.jpg

Comment: What happens when it 'fails'?

Comment: Why are you changing `folderPath` in your loop, destroying it for the next file? You should use a new `filepath` variable.

Comment: You are 'stacking' your var "folerPath"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destroying the `folderPath` in the loop:

```
var folderPath = openFolder.SelectedPath;

var fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.JPG");
float duration = 4;
float startpos = 0;
foreach (var file in fileArray) {
    var filePath = $@"{folderPath}\{file}";
    timelineControl.AddImageClip(timelineControl.GetImageTrackIndex(), filePath, startpos, (startpos + duration));
    startpos += 4;
}
```